# Add slashes (' / ') in date field using javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have this textbox:

```
<td width="10%"><input name="date" type="text" size=11 maxlength=10 /></td>
```

when typing date in the field it must add a forward slash in it like `09/02/2016`

Comment: `using javascript in php` ... php doesn't execute javascript

Comment: You need to use javascript or jQuery for this functionality.

Comment: and if i write agdfjhfaksfjfksadf in text field than

Comment: It is very unclear question.

Comment: and if i write agdfjhfaksfjfksadf in text field than i call "onblur" function to validate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was very ticky! This is how I got it working, though it's not complete as you will need to check for when a number is deleted

```
<input type="hidden" id='counter' value='0'>
<input name="date" id='date' type="text" size=11 maxlength=10 onkeydown="doDate()"/>

<script>
function doDate(){

var dateSoFar = document.getElementById("date");
var counter = parseInt(document.getElementById("counter").value);

counter = counter+1;

document.getElementById("counter").value = counter;

if(counter == 3 || counter == 5 )

document.getElementById("date").value = document.getElementById("date").value + '/';
}

</script>
```

Comment: This allows for dates that don't exist, ie 99/99/9999, and also breaks when entering multiple key presses at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same functionality in PHP using JS OR jQuery.

Replace

```
<input name="date" type="text" size=11 maxlength=10 />
```

To

```
<!-- SET type="date" -->
<input type="date" name="date">
```

**jQuery** Code:-

```
//Put our input DOM element into a jQuery Object
var $jqDate = jQuery('input[name="date"]');

//Bind keyup/keydown to the input
$jqDate.bind('keyup','keydown', function(e){

  //To accomdate for backspacing, we detect which key was pressed - if backspace, do nothing:
    if(e.which !== 8) { 
        var numChars = $jqDate.val().length;
        if(numChars === 2 || numChars === 5){
            var thisVal = $jqDate.val();
            thisVal += '/';
            $jqDate.val(thisVal);
        }
  }
});
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <input name="date" id='date' type="text" size=11 maxlength=10 onkeydown="updateDate()"/>

<script>
function updateDate(){
var dateSoFar = document.getElementById("date");
var counter = dateSoFar.value.length;
if(counter == 2 || counter == 5 )
 document.getElementById("date").value = document.getElementById("date").value + '/';
}
</script>
```